Failed to load image "". Reason: Unable to open file Failed to load map.png
I get this error code even if I got the "map.png" file in the executable directory, I think that my project is well configured with all the .lib / .dll file of SFML.
I have tried to create a folder in the executable, I also tried using absolute path, changing the project properties still the same problem of that .png
I'm making this with Visual Studio 2022 and SFML, I tried with this code but I got the output:
Failed to load image "". Reason: Unable to open file
Error: Could not load texture from file 'map.png'

When I try to start the program, I get this error, with a F5
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Map Example");

    sf::Texture texture;
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("map.png")) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Could not load texture from file 'map.png'" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sprite.setTexture(texture);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(sprite);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}



Thank you for the suggestion! I checked my working directory settings and it seems to be correct. I've attached a screenshot of the working directory configuration in my IDE. I also tried using the full path to map.png, but unfortunately, the issue persists. Here's the code I used with the absolute path:
if (!texture.loadFromFile("C:/Users/akram/source/repos/Project3/x64/Debug/map.png")) {
    std::cerr << "Error: Could not load texture from file 'map.png'" << std::endl;
    return -1;
} else {
    std::cerr << "Successfully loaded 'map.png'\n";
}

Screenshot of my folder with the PNG file
Screenshot of my working directory

As an experiment, try calling std::filesystem::exists to eliminate SFML and its binaries, as well as potential file search path and content issues from the equation.

Should I be worried that it's reporting an empty string "" as the name of the file that it couldn't load?  Are you redacting information or running different code from what you've put in the question?

I'm running the same code that i've put in the question.
And I tried calling std::filesystem::exists but I got the same error.

And I tried calling std::filesystem::exists but I got the same error Calling std::filesystem::exists was not supposed to fix the sfml problem at all. Instead it was supposed to tell you if the problem was caused an incorrect path to the image. Meaning the image really is not where you told your code it exists. One way that problem can happen is with the file explorer "hide extensions for known types" option. Sometimes this can confuse the situation where a file may have more than 1 extension.

When I get really desperate, I turn to the Process Monitor tool by SysInternals.  It will show you all the file system operations that your process is performing and you can see what file it actually tried to access and then confirm whether or not it is actually in that place.  You may not be running the code you think you are, or you may be running it from a different location, or in a path that is visually similar, or there may even be hidden unicode characters in your path.  But try Process Monitor and see what's up.

You can also try writing a dummy file to your working directory to see if your paths are correct.  e.g.:  std::ofstream output("evidence.txt");  And then see if evidence.txt gets created in the same folder as your map.png.

In Visual Studio Community / Enterprise / Pro the working directory is set to $(ProjectDir) when you run your code in the IDE (either running or debugging). This VS variable is the folder containing the project. So its likely: C:/Users/akram/source/repos/Project3 with that said if the full path didn't work something else is going on. This could be a library conflict like using a Release .lib for Debug or it could be caused by some type of other undefined behavior like a bug in your other code that corrupts the heap or it less likely could be a bug in the SFML code.

Also look in the output of Visual Studio during the debug and make sure the proper SFML dlls were loaded from the location where you installed it for this project. This type of bug could also be caused by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell where you had dlls of the same name in some other location on your drive and windows found that other incompatible version and used it instead of the dlls that match the .lib files you linked.

I meant Output Tab in the previous comment. When you debug in VS it will list each dll loaded with the full path on a line where it tells you if the symbols are loaded or not for the dll. Note: Don't stress out over a dll not loading symbols, that will not cause you a problem. It just prevents you from looking deep inside a dll when debugging (something you would likely rarely want to do).
